# How do you add $(document).ready(function() to joomla

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

I need to add this to joomla I've tried adding it to the template index.php file but it doesn't work any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("nav#menu").mmenu(
    {
      classes: "mm-light"
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: Hit F12 & look at console to check errors, u may have problem loading jquery or loading "mmenu" plugin.

Comment: I got it working on a normal website http://www.tenerifeguide.eu/ if you resize the browser you see the green menu bar popup and when you click the button the menu pops out the side but i just cant get it working on a Joomla website http://canary-islands-guide.com/ the menu bar is there but the pop-out function isn't working for some reason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're Joomla site is importing jQueury in noConflict mode, therefore you must either use the `jQuery` alias, or pass the `$` through the function, like so:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScriptDeclaration('
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       $("nav#menu").mmenu({
           classes: "mm-light"
       });
    });
');
```

The above code is PHP so you can place it anywhere in your template within PHP tags.

I've also noticed on your site that the responsive menu is now working. Tested in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I got the responsive menu to slide as you seen by changing the $(document) to jQuery(document) your method worked too but on both of them the drop downs don't work neither do the links im still trying to figure it out

Comment: Got it working now I had another menu in the way conflicting with the responsive menu thank you very much for your help :)